# Automapper preconditition, if src value is 0 then map null

Tags: c#, automapper

Hi I have a quick question I have a mapper config created that looks like:

```cs
CreateMap<ModifySystem, Entities.System>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.IpAddress, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => IPAddress.Parse(src.IpAddress)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ApplicationId, opt =>
    {
        opt.PreCondition(src => src.ApplicationId > 0 || src.ApplicationId == null);
        opt.MapFrom(src => src.ApplicationId);
    })
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opts => opts.Ignore());
```

Well it works when I get value bigger then 0 or null (ApplicationId  is nullable), but I want something that if source value will be 0 then set value as null.

Tried  `opt.MapFrom(src => null);` but it does not work as it should. How to solve this problem in autommaper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you have

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.IpAddress, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => IPAddress.Parse(src.IpAddress)))
```

You could do something like the following:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.ApplicationId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ApplicationId == null || src.ApplicationId == 0 ? null : src.ApplicationId ))
```